# How to store messages between users in database?

Tags: mysql, database, storage, message

I am building a small e-mail like messaging app for a project, where a user would send out a message to another with information like meeting times and such, and I'm wondering about how to store all the messages exchanged.
My issues are:

- Should I store all messages between all users in one database table (where it would be expensive to get the messages of each user when they log in)? Or should each user have a personal table for his/her messages(would have too many tables)?
- I also need to store the events that the user accepts. Again, should these be in one table for all users or a separate table for each (I need to retrieve these quite often)?

I've searched on the site for other similar questions but most seem to focus on real-time messaging or on specific implementation technologies.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: When you make your design decisions we can assist.. unless you are looking for guidance 1 way vs the other.   Its pertty simple and straight forward to develop.  I usually maintain a history with a trigger to delete stuff over a year.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! This isn't really a well-suited question for the site - SO is meant more for questions of the "help, I'm stuck with [details on programming issue]" variety. That said, your question is easy to answer: unless you have a very good reason to go with lots of tables - don't. If it becomes a huge issue because of a huge number users, you can optimise in various ways later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table per user is a bad idea. It means every query will be different and for every new user you will need to modify the database. This is hard to build, hard to maintain, and inefficient for your database too.

So, just store it in one table. A couple of millions of rows won't be a problem if you have proper indexes (and proper hardware).

If you fear for bad performance, you may delete very old messages. Or you can move them to an 'archive' table. If a user wants to view recent messages (of the past year or so), they can get it from the normal table, and older messages can be fetched from the other one. It's usually acceptable that digging into the archives is a bit slower, so it's probably okay if that table grows very large.

That said, you already mentioned e-mail. I'd seriously consider inspecting the possibilities of actual e-mail and the post boxes that come with it. There are many existing implementations, and it's a powerful protocol that has survived since the dawn of the internet, so maybe you shouldn't reinvent the wheel.

E-mail can have headers (custom headers too), and multiple parts, so even if a 'normal' e-mail won't suffice, you can still use e-mail as a transport layer for custom types of messages.